# postman grapqhl - schema import gives "Syntax Error: Expected Name, found String "data"

Tags: graphql, postman

postman's new graphql handing doesnt seem to work.

On its own its unable to query schemas (because it doesnt send the right request), but if you manually send the schema query:

```
query IntrospectionQuery {
    __schema {
        queryType {
            name
        }
        mutationType {
            name
        }
        subscriptionType {
            name
        }
        types {
            ...FullType
        }
        directives {
            name
            description
            locations
            args {
                ...InputValue
            }
        }
    }
}

fragment FullType on __Type {
    kind
    name
    description
    fields(includeDeprecated: true) {
        name
        description
        args {
            ...InputValue
        }
        type {
            ...TypeRef
        }
        isDeprecated
        deprecationReason
    }
    inputFields {
        ...InputValue
    }
    interfaces {
        ...TypeRef
    }
    enumValues(includeDeprecated: true) {
        name
        description
        isDeprecated
        deprecationReason
    }
    possibleTypes {
        ...TypeRef
    }
}

fragment InputValue on __InputValue {
    name
    description
    type {
        ...TypeRef
    }
    defaultValue
}

fragment TypeRef on __Type {
    kind
    name
    ofType {
        kind
        name
        ofType {
            kind
            name
            ofType {
                kind
                name
                ofType {
                    kind
                    name
                    ofType {
                        kind
                        name
                        ofType {
                            kind
                            name
                            ofType {
                                kind
                                name
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

What you get back is something like this:

```
{
    "data": {
        "__schema": {
            "queryType": {
                "name": "Query"
            },
            "mutationType": {
                "name": "Mutation"
            },
            "subscriptionType": {
                "name": "Subscription"
            },
            "types": [
```

If we now save this to a file such as schema.json, then try to "import schema", it gives the error:

```
Could not load GraphQL schema.

Syntax Error: Expected Name, found String "data".
```

Any ideas for a workaround?  Introspection does not work either.

Comment: If this is an issue, I'd recommend raising it here: https://github.com/postmanlabs/postman-app-support/issues to get it in front of the people who can help fix it.

Comment: thanks for the reply. Im hoping someone will say how I convert the graphql schema I get back to something which can be read by postman.   I suspect its a user error :o

Answer (score 0):

I  ran into this same issue, it appears Postman wants SDL format rather than json.  There are several ways to convert it, however I just used an online converter I found here (not mine): https://codesandbox.io/s/graphql-introspection-sdl-svlx2